# Reference to current object in Jquery chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollable, jquery-chaining

The following chain works:

```
    $("</p>").html('message').hide().appendTo("#chat").fadeIn()
.parent().scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
```

But this doesn't:

```
    $("</p>").html('message').hide().appendTo("#chat").fadeIn()
.parent().scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
```

`this.scrollHeight` doesn't work too.
How can i get current object reference in jquery chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get access to the current object inside of a callback. There's no way you can get access to the current object in your chain.

Try this:

```
var $parent = $("</p>").html('message').hide().appendTo("#chat").fadeIn().parent();
$parent.scrollTop($parent[0].scrollHeight);
```

---

If you *really* don't want to break out of you chain, you can re-select:

```
$("</p>").html('message').hide().appendTo("#chat").fadeIn()
.parent().scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);
```

But I'd strongly advise you against it. There's no need to select the same DOM element twice.

Answer (score 1):

In your second code snippet `this` doesn't point to `#chat` that's why it doesn't work. `this` mostly points to the calling function instance or the object which triggered any event.

You can try something like this

```
var $p = $("</p>").html('message').hide().appendTo("#chat");

$p.fadeIn().parent().scrollTop($p[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's obvious. The `#chat` element is a static element and you are dynamically appending paragraphs to it. Therefore, you want to **get a reference to that element beforehand** (for instance, on page initialization):

```
var chat = $( '#chat' )[0];
```

Now, you do this:

```
$( '<p />' ).html( 'message' ).hide().appendTo( chat ).fadeIn();
$( chat ).scrollTop( chat.scrollHeight );
```

So, the idea is to retrieve references to the main static elements (chat-box, toolbar, panel, navigation, etc.) on page initialization, and then use those references all over your application code.

Comment: Doesn't $('#chat')[0] return the dom element vs. $('#chat').eq(0) which would return a jquery set?

Comment: @DyeA Yes, in my code, `chat` is a reference to the DOM element. I prefer to keep my references "clean", instead of wrapped in jQuery objects.

Comment: Ugh: "Well, it's obvious." It's obviously not obvious to OP.